# JQuery work but only when i reload page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to do dynamic select box in ruby. JQuery looks like this:

```
jQuery ->
$('#person_state_id').parent().hide()
states = $('#person_state_id').html()
$('#person_country_id').change ->
 country = $('#person_country_id :selected').text()
escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
options = $(states).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_country}']").html()
if options
  $('#person_state_id').html(options)
  $('#person_state_id').parent().show()
else
  $('#person_state_id').empty()
  $('#person_state_id').parent().hide()
```

and in view:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :state_id, Country.order(:name), :states, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

It's work but... when i go to my page at example.com/person/new - it doesn't work. I must reload page - and then everything is OK... Why it doesn't it load the JQuery on first visit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your function inside `$(document).ready()` to load items in listbox.
This function will load your functionality during page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //your function;
});
```

Comment: i put this JQ in person.js.coffe - maybe its a problem? But when i make other like select_box.js - it doesny work at all... im very beginner

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?view=comments - its this railcast and i do exacly like tutorial

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881384/jquery-gets-loaded-only-on-page-refresh-in-rails-4-application),

In Rails 4.0, just add this to your Gemfile:

> gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

and this to your assets/javascripts/application.js file:

> //= require jquery.turbolinks